# Arping command is always returning exit value 2. How to fix this?

Tags: android

Actually I am trying to run command "arping -c 5 -I wlan0 gatewayaddr" in Android Studio. Here gateway address is any ip address. But every time i execute this command i am getting exit value 2. My android device is already rooted device. And if i run this command in adb shell then i am getting the proper result but in code i am getting the exit value 2. How i can fix this to get exit value 0?

```
Process proc = runtime.exec("arping -c 5 -I wlan0 <gatewayaddr>");
        proc.waitFor();
        int exit = proc.exitValue();enter code here
```